# How to composite two varbinaries

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, varbinary

I have two varbinary masks:

```
@mask1  = 0x0000000000000001

@mask65 = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000003
```

**I have to**

1) **composite** them to get something like this `@mask_composite = @mask1 | @mask65`

2) **check** `@mask_composite & @mask2 > 0`

How can I do that by using T-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.dmertl.com/blog/?p=6) some guy shares [a solution](http://www.dmertl.com/files/posts/binary_bitwise.sql).

It's a function that splits varbinaries into ints, applies bitwise logic and merges it back.